# Difference between compress test.min.css and compress test.css

Tags: css, less, minify

I just started working for a new employer.
For my last employer we used LESS and compile it to a .css file and then compress it to a .min.css file. For my new employer we also use LESS. But here we not only compile the LESS file but also compress it to .css file.

Is there a difference between two different ways of working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minified version (.min.css) makes the file small by removing all the whitespaces. This makes it load faster for users.

So for working no difference (if any of it not  updated separately)